# Node Js app crashes after rebooting postgres server

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, crash, containers

I have :

- One docker container containing a server with a `node-js` app.
- One docker container containing a `postgres` database.
- There is a connection between these two.

Once I reboot the Postgres server the app crashes and wont restart until I manually restart it.

I'm using `pm2` to run the `nodejs` app and thats what I get when pm2 logs

```
 [TAILING] Tailing last 15 lines for [all] processes (change the value with --lines option)
/root/.pm2/pm2.log last 15 lines:
PM2        | 2021-09-22T12:58:58: PM2 log: pid=1947 msg=process killed
PM2        | 2021-09-22T12:58:58: PM2 log: App [myApp:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2021-09-22T12:58:58: PM2 log: App [myApp:0] online
PM2        | 2021-09-22T13:00:24: PM2 log: Change detected on path package.json.989998446 for app myApp - restarting
PM2        | 2021-09-22T13:00:24: PM2 log: Stopping app:myApp id:0
PM2        | 2021-09-22T13:00:24: PM2 log: App [myApp:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2021-09-22T13:00:24: PM2 log: pid=1955 msg=process killed
PM2        | 2021-09-22T13:00:24: PM2 log: App [myApp:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2021-09-22T13:00:24: PM2 log: App [myApp:0] online
PM2        | 2021-09-22T13:00:25: PM2 log: Change detected on path package-lock.json.95280979 for app myApp - restarting
PM2        | 2021-09-22T13:00:25: PM2 log: Stopping app:myApp id:0
PM2        | 2021-09-22T13:00:25: PM2 log: App [myApp:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2021-09-22T13:00:25: PM2 log: pid=2005 msg=process killed
PM2        | 2021-09-22T13:00:25: PM2 log: App [myApp:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2021-09-22T13:00:25: PM2 log: App [myApp:0] online

/root/.pm2/logs/myApp-error.log last 15 lines:
0|myApp    |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
0|myApp    |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
0|myApp    |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
0|myApp    | /home/ubuntu/Project/bootcamp-app/node_modules/postgres/lib/backend.js:177
0|myApp    |     if (backend.query.result.command) {
0|myApp    |                       ^
0|myApp    |
0|myApp    | TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined
0|myApp    |     at Object.RowDescription (/home/ubuntu/Project/bootcamp-app/node_modules/postgres/lib/backend.js:177:23)
0|myApp    |     at Socket.data (/home/ubuntu/Project/bootcamp-app/node_modules/postgres/lib/connection.js:161:25)
0|myApp    |     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
0|myApp    |     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
0|myApp    |     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
0|myApp    |     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
0|myApp    |     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)

/root/.pm2/logs/myApp-out.log last 15 lines:
0|myApp    |   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
0|myApp    |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
0|myApp    |   syscall: 'connect',
0|myApp    |   address: '**.**.***.***',//edited that for safety
0|myApp    |   port: 5432
0|myApp    | }
0|myApp    | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED **.**.***.***:5432
0|myApp    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
0|myApp    |   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
0|myApp    |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
0|myApp    |   syscall: 'connect',
0|myApp    |   address: '**.**.***.***',
0|myApp    |   port: 5432
0|myApp    | }
0|myApp    | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

any suggestions?

Comment: It seems the connection is not working between your postgres and your nodejs app. Can you share with us the content of your DockerfileS or of your docker-compose file ?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using keepalive in your connection string? It seems to me that the app is not really 'crashing' meaning it is still running so pm2 does not restart it, however you probably have the connection done at the start of the application, so the connection gets lost and cant reconnect

Comment: You have to reconnect once you are disconnected. How you do this depends alot how you handle this kind of stuff on starting your app. If your application design does not allow a reconnect, you have to refactor your code or restart the node app on every db restart.

Comment: Are the two components on the same physical host, or on different systems?  (If they're on different systems, the application is running using a non-Docker native Node installation, and the database is in a container on the other host – a pretty reasonable setup on the whole – then Docker shouldn't be that relevant to the combined system.)